# Sharepoint 101 - need some clarifications - Farm/Site/Project

Tags: 2010, document, project-server

I am trying to get an understanding of how the sharepoint server works, and some basic

I installed a new server 2008R2 with Sharepoint 2010 - Is that the farm?

I installed a project Server 2010 on that SP Server - Is that a site?

I have a project setup on a certain port: is that my Web Project App?

Need some SP 101 - thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome to SP.SE Saariko. This question would take a book to answer, but you can start learning quickly if you just Google a little. Here is a University Course in [SharePoint 101](http://www.ucdenver.edu/about/departments/WebServices/sharepoint/onlineTraining/101basics/Pages/default.aspx)

Comment: thank, been trolling here for a while. That 101 is what I missed while googling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have SharePoint 2010 installed on a single WS2008r2 server, then yes - that's you're single server farm. 
When you installed Project Server 2010 on that server, you added the ability to create sites that integrate with the project server application.

The project server application runs within the sharepoint farm, not (as far as I know) on a specific port.
You can set up a web application to run on a specific URL, e.g. Project.firm.com.
Then via central admin you can create a project server site - look where the project server service app is configured.